# PyQt5 При нажатии на кнопку класса Push Button программа завершается, не выводя ответ

Tags: python, pyqt5

Моя программа должна при нажатии на кнопку `Inicialization` вызывать функцию `getArr`, которая  выводит в виджете `InputArr` перемешанную последовательность от 1 до 10, но при нажатии программа самопроизвольно завершается, не выводя ошибки. В чем проблема?

```
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets, QtGui
import sys


class MyWin(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        QtWidgets.QWidget.__init__(self, parent)
        self.ui = Ui_MainWindow()
        self.ui.setupUi(self)
        self.arr = []
        self.len_arr = 0
        self.n = 10

        self.ui.Inicialization.clicked.connect(self.getArr)

    #функция, при нажатии на кнопку Inicialization
    def getArr(self, n=10):
        for i in range(n):
            self.arr.append(i+1)
        random.shuffle(self.arr)
        self.ui.InputArr.setText(str(self.arr))


if __name__ =="__main__":
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    application = MyWin()
    application.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec())
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Проблема в том, что вы не опубликовали модуль, содержащий класс `Ui_MainWindow` и в подключении кнопки к слоту через сигнал `clicked`.

```
import sys
import random
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets, QtGui


class MyWin(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        QtWidgets.QWidget.__init__(self, parent)

#        self.ui = Ui_MainWindow()
#        self.ui.setupUi(self)
        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget()
        self.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)

        self.InputArr = QtWidgets.QLabel()
        self.Inicialization = QtWidgets.QPushButton('Inicialization')

        layout = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout(self.centralwidget)
        layout.addWidget(self.InputArr)
        layout.addWidget(self.Inicialization)


        self.arr = []
        self.len_arr = 0
        self.n = 10

        self.Inicialization.clicked.connect(lambda ch, n=self.n: self.getArr(n))     # <-----

    #функция, при нажатии на кнопку Inicialization
    def getArr(self, n):
        for i in range(n):
            self.arr.append(i+1)
        print(self.arr)
        random.shuffle(self.arr)
        self.InputArr.setText(str(self.arr))


if __name__ =="__main__":
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    application = MyWin()
    application.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]